# Should I ever use getMeasuredState() in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, measure

I have a complex custom logic for my layout, which relies on child states: if any of children has not enough space, every child is asked to use its custom condensed state.

**How I expected it to be**

As the  [getMeasuredState ()](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/View.html#getMeasuredState()) says:

> Return only the state bits of getMeasuredWidthAndState() and getMeasuredHeightAndState(), combined into one integer. The width component is in the regular bits MEASURED_STATE_MASK and the height component is at the shifted bits MEASURED_HEIGHT_STATE_SHIFT>>MEASURED_STATE_MASK.

I supposed, we can ask every child after each measurement if it's too constrained with the help of measured state. So my layout implementation is extended from `LinearLayout` and adds the following:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    expand();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (isTooSmall()) {
        condense();
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

/**
* return true if any child has TOO_SMALL flag
*/
private boolean isTooSmall(){
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if (child != null){
            //I'm interested in width only                
            int measuredState = child.getMeasuredState() & MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL;
            if (measuredState != 0) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**What it turned out to be**

`child.getMeasuredState()` returns 0, no matter, if they are clipped or not (layout has exact width). All my child views are extended from the `TextView`, and looking through the source code, I found out that `TextView` doesn't use that measurement state bits at all! Why is it so, and where should I know about that from??

**The questions**

When should we rely on that MEASURED_STATE_MASK? If even framework components (api 23) can easily ignore that, how can we be sure, that it will work? I guess there is totally no guarantee for any `View`, that the real state in layout and the result of `getMeasuredState()` are the same things. OR it is just a case for the `TextView`-like classes, that are supposed never to have `TOO_SMALL` state (if it so, then why)??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's returning 0 because it's `onLayout()` and `onMeasure()` methods have been incorrectly implemented?

When they aren't implemented correctly, it takes a View a while to find out it's real size - if it even 'finds' it out and changes the value from 0 to something else.

Try these two methods:

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int desiredWidth = 100;
    int desiredHeight = 100;

    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    int width;
    int height;

    //Measure Width
    if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        width = widthSize;
    } else if(widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        width = Math.min(desiredWidth, widthSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        width = desiredWidth;
    }

    //Measure Height
    if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
        //Must be this size
        height = heightSize;
    } else if(heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        //Can't be bigger than...
        height = Math.min(desiredHeight, heightSize);
    } else {
        //Be whatever you want
        height = desiredHeight;
    }

    //MUST CALL THIS
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

    linear_rootLayout.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, widthMode), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, heightMode));
    measureChildren(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, widthMode), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, heightMode));
    super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, widthMode), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, heightMode));
}

    @Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final int count = getChildCount();
    int curWidth, curHeight, curLeft, curTop, maxHeight;

    //get the available size of child view
    int childLeft = this.getPaddingLeft();
    int childTop = this.getPaddingTop();
    int childRight = this.getMeasuredWidth() - this.getPaddingRight();
    int childBottom = this.getMeasuredHeight() - this.getPaddingBottom();
    int childWidth = childRight - childLeft;
    int childHeight = childBottom - childTop;

    maxHeight = 0;
    curLeft = childLeft;
    curTop = childTop;
    //walk through each child, and arrange it from left to right
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View child = getChildAt(i);
        if(child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
            //Get the maximum size of the child
            child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidth, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childHeight, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
            curWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
            curHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            //wrap is reach to the end
            if(curLeft + curWidth >= childRight) {
                curLeft = childLeft;
                curTop += maxHeight;
                maxHeight = 0;
            }
            //do the layout
            child.layout(curLeft, curTop, curLeft + curWidth, curTop + curHeight);
            //store the max height
            if(maxHeight < curHeight) maxHeight = curHeight;
            curLeft += curWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe they change something for you. Maybe you need to implement the `measure()` and `layout()` methods as well.

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve with these methods in your use-case to be honest.

Comment: I don't touch the process of measurement itself - it's implemented in LinearLayout, that I extend in my layout, and in TextView, that I use for its children, so it is 100% correct.
"what you're trying to achieve .. " - I need to know if the child will be cropped. And it turned out, that it's impossible by means of `getMeasuredState()`

Comment: btw, we're talking exactly about states, not the sizes - the size values returned are correct, however, I did expected the `MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL` bit to appear, when your `TextView` is interrupted in mid-sentence

Comment: thanks for that hint about taking a while in measurement - need to experiment with that))

Comment: You can get a callback when the measuring is done by using a `GlobalTreeObserver` but as far as states go - sorry, none of what i stated here helps you with that.

Comment: TextView does not set MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL even when singleLine="true" is set.